# How to apply singleton design pattern without a method that is not a constructor to return class object

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I have recently started working on a very old project and from the beginning of the project design pattern was not properly used. Now in one situation I want to make an already existing class a singleton class. In most tutorials I have seen that singleton classes uses a method to return object reference, like getInstance() in the following. Problem is everywhere in the project object is declared without help of any method except constructor. Is there any way to modify existing class so that without changing object creation method i can implement singleton pattern?

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static Singleton *single;
    Singleton()
    {
        //private constructor
    }
public:
    static Singleton* getInstance();
    void method();
    ~Singleton()
    {
        instanceFlag = false;
    }
};

bool Singleton::instanceFlag = false;
Singleton* Singleton::single = NULL;
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
{
    if(! instanceFlag)
    {
        single = new Singleton();
        instanceFlag = true;
        return single;
    }
    else
    {
        return single;
    }
}
void Singleton::method()
{
    cout << "Method of the singleton class" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Singleton *sc1,*sc2;
    sc1 = Singleton::getInstance();
    sc1->method();
    sc2 = Singleton::getInstance();
    sc2->method();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pimpl idiom to do that, but remember, singletron are a bad design patterns, once you are dealing, in fact, with global variables.

Below is a simple program showing how you can do that. Note that I'm to dealing with single life time, just showing the concept:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SingletonImpl
{
public:
    void method() {
        cout << "Method of the singleton class" << endl;
    }
};

class Singleton
{
private:
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static SingletonImpl *single;
public:
    Singleton()
    {
        if ( !instanceFlag ) {
            single = new SingletonImpl();
            instanceFlag = true;
        }
    }

    void method();
    ~Singleton()
    {
        // Do your life time management here
    }
};


bool Singleton::instanceFlag = false;
SingletonImpl* Singleton::single = NULL;

void Singleton::method()
{
    single->method();
}

int main()
{
    Singleton *sc1,*sc2;
    sc1 = new Singleton();
    sc1->method();
    sc2 = new Singleton();
    sc2->method();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In old source code object is declared in this way Singleton obj. Is it possible to apply singleton by using the old way of object declaration?

Comment: What you need to do is to manage the life time of your singletonImpl. You can do this by using reference count to take care about  the amount of singleton instantiations or, if your application support it, by never deallocating your singletonImpl.